# standard deviation of time in a column in hr:min:sec format

Tags: r, chron

In the question ["average time in a column in hr:min:sec format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281134/average-time-in-a-column-in-hrminsec-format) the following example is given:

```
Col_Time = c('03:08:20','03:11:30','03:22:18','03:27:39')
library(chron)
mean(times(Col_Time))
[1] 03:17:27
```

How can I get hr:min:sec as result for the standard deviation? If I use the R function **sd**, the result looks like that:

```
sd(times(Col_Time))
[1] 0.006289466
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sd` is operating on the number internally representing the time (days for `chron::times`, seconds for `hms` and `POSIXct`, settable for `difftime`), which is fine. The only problem is that it is dropping the class from the result so it isn't printed nicely. The solution, then, is just to convert back to the time class afterwards:

```r
x <- c('03:08:20','03:11:30','03:22:18','03:27:39')

chron::times(sd(chron::times(x)))
#> [1] 00:09:03

hms::as.hms(sd(hms::as.hms(x)))
#> 00:09:03.409836

as.POSIXct(sd(as.POSIXct(x, format = '%H:%M:%S')), 
           tz = 'UTC', origin = '1970-01-01')
#> [1] "1970-01-01 00:09:03 UTC"

as.difftime(sd(as.difftime(x, units = 'secs')), 
            units = 'secs')
#> Time difference of 543.4098 secs
```

Comment: Good to see that our results are matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate` package. The `hms` function will convert time from characters to `HMS` format. Then use `seconds` to convert to seconds and calculate `mean/sd`. Finally, use `seconds_to_period` to get the result in `HMS` format.

```
library(lubridate)
Col_Time = c('03:08:20','03:11:30','03:22:18','03:27:39')

#Get the mean
seconds_to_period(mean(seconds(hms(Col_Time))))
# [1] "3H 17M 26.75S"

#Get the sd
seconds_to_period(sd(seconds(hms(Col_Time))))
#[1] "9M 3.40983612739285S"
```